# Orthogonal Complex Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $M_{2\times2}(\Bbb C)$ together with the inner product $<A,B>=Trace(B^\dagger A)$, where $B^\dagger$ is conjugated.  Let $W$ be the subspace defined by

$W= \left \{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}:a+b+c=0, a=d\right \}$

a) Find an orthogonal basis for $W$.

I found the basis (not orthogonal), for $W$ to span $\left (\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}, \; \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}\right )$.  But because we are dealing with complex matrices instead of $1's$ should they be $i's$.  I am not sure what the significance is of conjugated matrix which terms are only real numbers, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"because we are dealing with complex matrices instead of 1′s should they be i′s."*  What?

Comment: $1$ is a real number.  It's also a complex number.

Comment: So $B^T$ being conjugated is more for the definition instead of actually being used, because a real number conjugated is just the number itself.

Comment: exactly.  The answer here would be exactly the same if we were looking at real matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have a basis of $W$.  One way to make this into an *orthogonal* basis is to use Gram Schmidt.  Denote
$$
A_1 = \pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1}, \quad
A_2 = \pmatrix{-1&0\\1&-1}
$$
Instead of using $A_2$ for our basis, we will extract the component of $A_2$ perpendicular to $A_1$ and use that.  In particular, we take
$$
A_0 = A_2 - 
\frac{\langle A_2,A_1 \rangle}{\langle A_1,A_1 \rangle} A_1 =\\
\pmatrix{-1&0\\1&-1} - 
\frac{2}{3} \pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1} = \\
\pmatrix{-1/3&-2/3\\1&-1/3}
$$
So, the set
$$
\pmatrix{-1&1\\0&-1},
\pmatrix{-1/3&-2/3\\1&-1/3}
$$
forms an *orthogonal* basis of $W$, as you may verify.

---

Another good choice of basis would have been
$$
\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&2}, \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$